# Custom document classes with embedable external macros?

Tags: macros, document-classes

I'm fairly new to LaTeX so I don't really know much yet.

Is there a way I can make a custom document class that embeds an external document containing custom macros?

For example, I have right now a **MyBook.cls** file with a few small changes from the default **Book** document class. I would also like to define a bunch of `\newcommand{}` macros, but I don't want to have to do it in every custom document class.

Comment: You can put your `\newcommand` in a `mycommands.sty` or `mycommands.tex` file and then load it using, respectively `\usepackage{mycommands}` or `\input{mycommands.tex}`

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a file (or 'package' --- say `mycustomcmds.sty`) that contains several macros you want to use in many different documents that all use `MyBook.cls`?  I think this can be done with `\usepackage{mycustomcmds}`.  But perhaps you have something trickier in mind..?

Comment: A package did the job, thanks. Had no idea I could easily make my own package like that. Now I can just `\usepackage` on my custom list of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package is what I was looking for. I just made a custom .sty file and now I can load it whenever I wish.